Inconsistent Game Speed and Meteor Falling Rate after Restarting
After restarting my game using a button, I'm encountering inconsistent game speed and meteor falling rates compared to the initial game launch. Initially, the game runs smoothly with quick meteor falls and fighter jet movement. However, upon restarting the game, the meteors seem to fall slower, and the fighter jet moves at a reduced speed. I suspect this inconsistency might be due to how I'm handling the game loop or thread usage. Any help on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
I'm going to show Game.java, where the game loop and reset functionality are implemented.
package main;

import entity.FighterJet;
import entity.Meteor;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    final int windowWidth = 600;
    final int windowHeight = 600;
    int FPS = 60;
    KeyHandler handler = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameLoopThread;
    FighterJet fighterJet;
    List<Meteor> meteors;
    Random random;
    boolean gameOver = false;
    Menu menu;
    JFrame gameWindow;

    public Game(Menu menu, JFrame gameWindow) {
        this.menu = menu;
        this.gameWindow = gameWindow;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowWidth, windowHeight));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        addKeyListener(handler);

        fighterJet = new FighterJet(300, 500, 8);
        meteors = new ArrayList<>();
        random = new Random();
    }

    public void startGameLoopThread() {
        if (gameLoopThread != null && gameLoopThread.isAlive()) {
            gameLoopThread.interrupt(); // Interrupt the previous game loop thread
        }
        gameLoopThread = new Thread(this);
        gameLoopThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = (double) 1000000000 / FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;

        while (gameLoopThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            lastTime = currentTime;

            if (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                checkCollisions();
                delta--;
            }

            if (gameOver) {
                displayGameOver();
                break; // Exit the loop when game is over
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        updateJet();
        generateMeteors();
        updateMeteors();
    }

    private void updateJet() {
        if (handler.move_left && !handler.move_right) {
            fighterJet.update(true, false); // Move left
            fighterJet.updateImage(1);
        } else if (handler.move_right && !handler.move_left) {
            fighterJet.update(false, true); // Move right
            fighterJet.updateImage(2);
        } else {
            fighterJet.update(false, false); // No movement
            fighterJet.updateImage(0);
        }
    }


    private void generateMeteors() {
        int meteorSpawnChance = 6;
        int maxNumMeteors = 8;
        if (meteors.size() < maxNumMeteors && random.nextInt(100) < meteorSpawnChance) {
            int randomX = random.nextInt(windowWidth);
            int speed = random.nextInt(3) + 4; // Random speed between 4 and 6
            meteors.add(new Meteor(randomX, 0, speed));
        }
    }

    private void updateMeteors() {
        List<Meteor> meteorsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Meteor meteor : new ArrayList<>(meteors)) {
            meteor.update();
            if (meteor.getY() > windowHeight) {
                meteorsToRemove.add(meteor);
            }
        }
        meteors.removeAll(meteorsToRemove);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        fighterJet.draw(g2);

        // Create a copy of the meteors list to iterate over
        List<Meteor> meteorsCopy = new ArrayList<>(meteors);
        for (Meteor meteor : meteorsCopy) {
            g2.drawImage(meteor.getCurrentImage(), meteor.getX(), meteor.getY(), 20, 50, null);
        }
        g2.dispose();

        if (gameOver) {
            displayGameOver();
        }
    }

    public void checkCollisions() {
        for (Meteor meteor : meteors) {
            if (fighterJet.getBounds().intersects(meteor.getBounds())) {
                gameOver = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayGameOver() {
        if (gameOver) {
            gameLoopThread.interrupt();
            GameOver gameOverScreen = new GameOver(gameWindow, menu,this);
            gameWindow.getContentPane().removeAll();
            gameWindow.add(gameOverScreen);
            gameWindow.pack();
        }
    }

    public void resetGame() {
        gameOver = false;
        meteors.clear();
        generateMeteors(); // Generate new meteors after clearing
        handler.resetFighterJetMovement();
        fighterJet = new FighterJet(300, 500, 8);
        addKeyListener(handler);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        startGameLoopThread(); // Start the game loop again
    }
}


Note you call Thread#interrupt, but this does nothing if the other thread doesn't check Thread#isInterrupted or Thread#interrupted. I'd venture to guess that you never end your threads, you just continue spawning more of them. That said, there are nicer classes (like ScheduledExecutorService and CompletableFuture) that allow for async processing in a more effecient and less error-prone manner, I'd recommend taking a look at those as an alternative approach (particularly the scheduler in place of threads). There's also virtual threads, but one step at a time.

I believe you are trying to manipulate the GUI on a thread which is not the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Refer to Concurrency in Swing.

Also agree that you just continue to spawn more thread since your game over logic creates a new instance of the game component. Instead. you should have logic to reset the state of the game back to its original state.

AWT and Swing are single-threaded.  All Swing methods need to called in one and only one thread, the AWT event dispatch thread.  If you call them in any other thread, the behavior is undefined—which means it might work sometimes, might fail other times, might fail on other computers, and so on.  Simply put, violating the threading rules will make your program unstable.
What this means is that you cannot call methods like update, checkCollisions, and displayGameOver from a Thread you yourself created.
What you can do instead is use a javax.swing.Timer (which is not the same class as java.util.Timer):
private Timer gameLoopTimer;

public void startGameLoopThread() {
    int drawInterval = 1000 / FPS;

    if (gameLoopTimer != null) {
        gameLoopTimer.stop();
    }

    gameLoopTimer = new Timer(drawInterval, e -> run());
    gameLoopTimer.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    update();
    repaint();
    checkCollisions();

    if (gameOver) {
        displayGameOver();
        gameLoopTimer.stop();
    }
}

Your old version of run() was a loop with no sleeps or waits in it.  It was running constantly, chewing up CPU time and taking CPU time away from Swing.  (In theory, each thread would use its own CPU core… unless, of course, other software is using those CPU cores, including the operating system, any background services which are running, and any web browsers or mail clients that happen to be running.)
A Timer won’t have those problems, because it waits for the interval time instead of constantly running and polling the time.
Some other notes:

Remove g2.dispose();.  Never dispose of a Graphics unless you yourself created it.  The Graphics passed to painting methods belongs to the system, and is not yours to dispose of.
Remove the if (gameOver) check and its associated body from the paintComponent method.  For one thing, the run method already does that check;  for another thing, painting methods can be called by the system at any time for a variety of reasons, most of which are not under your control, so program logic should never be in painting methods.


Thank you for your help. It's now smooth even if I click on the restart button. I changed the speed of the meteors. They have varying speeds. I also changed the FPS to 100. It works fine now. Do you think this is good.
`public void startGameLoop() {
int drawInterval = 100 / FPS;
int speed = random.nextInt(3) + 8; // Random speed between 4 and 6`

No.  The 1000 represents the number of milliseconds in one second.  If you want to change the FPS, change the value of the FPS variable.  The interval must remain 1000 / FPS.  As for your speed variable, I don’t know how you’re using it, so I am unable to say whether it’s a good thing or not.

Alright. Thank you. Everything works. Just a last question. I'm just wondering, what is a typical value for FPS.

I’ve only written a few games, so I’m not qualified to answer that question.  When I play games, 30 FPS seems pretty smooth to me, but a lot of avid gamers think 60 FPS (or higher!) is important.  You might want to search gamedev.stackexchange.com for discussions on ideal frame rates.

Keep in mind game ticks and visual rendering are typically done separately. For instance, minecraft often has a 20tps (ticks-per-second) game loop, which is roughly 50ms per tick. But the actual visual render updates may occur more frequently, as interpolation on the client may make more incremental changes. In short, try targetting 30/60/120 fps just as a baseline for visual effects, but note this means you have less time to render (33ms, 17ms, and 8ms, respectively), and going over that time may cause visual quirks/defects.
